# OCR for the OCR-B standard font

Tags: ocr, font-utility

I am looking for a software/library (preferably open-source) to read bitmaps containing texts in the OCR-B font, which is used e.g. in passports machine readable zone. I have tried tesseract, but it gives me poor results. I assume that this has to be a solved problem, when OCR-B is international standard so I'd think that such software is is not exclusive to airport staff, but I am unable to find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tired [OCRSDK.com](http://ocrsdk.com) from ABBYY? It is not open-source, but has some amount of free usage for beginners. Very high accuracy. [Here](http://cloud.ocrsdk.com/Demo/) you can play around with your own images without any registration and see what it is capable of.

Disclaimer: I work for ABBYY.